# Getting thumbnails for .MTS (AVCHD) video files in Caja?

Tags: 16.04, video, mate, filemanager, thumbnails

In Caja (MATE's file manager), I'm not getting thumbnails for .MTS video files (From my [AVCHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD) camera). However, if I rename them to a more common extension, such as `.mp4`, thumbnails for them *are* generated.

How do I add `.MTS` files to the list of file extensions to generate thumbnails for, so that I don't have to rename them to get thumbnails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Caja but Nautilus; anyway I think they share this behaviour:
Nautilus thumbnail generation relies upon `ffmpegthumbnailer` which is controlled by `/usr/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer`.

Edit it in order to tell ffmpegthumbnailer to generate thumbnail also for that kind of file

Comment: Adding the mimetype `video/mp2t` to `ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer` makes the thumbnails show up, thanks !

Comment: perfect! I think you can open a bug report in the ffmpegthumbnailer bugtracker (or elsewhere you must fill it...) in order to make this change the default, IF works